# How to make the native functions visible on a custom class in python

Tags: python, class, logging

I'm a new-bie to programming and have started learning classes. for my requirement i wrote a custom logging class and i'm trying to make the native functions of the logging module visible from another class on the same file. when i print dir(res) inside the customLogger it lists out all the native functions of the logging module . (as an exmaple info ()) but when i try to get the class object from another function, the native functions are not visibile.

The code that I had written is:

```
class customLogger():
    def __init__(self, logLevel = logging.DEBUG):
        self.logLevel = logLevel
        res = self.custLog(self.logLevel)
        print(dir(res) >>>> here the info() method is visible.
    
    def custLog(self, logLevel):
        logger_name = inspect.stack()[1][3]
        logger = logging.getLogger(logger_name)
        logger.setLevel(self.logLevel)
        fh = logging.FileHandler("iperf.log", mode='w')
        formatter = fh.setFormatter('%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(name)s : %(message)s')
        fh.setFormatter(formatter)
        logger.addHandler(fh)
        return logger
```

```
class iperf3():
    def __init__(self, server_ip):
        #Creationg the Logger
        log = customLogger(). >>>> here the info() method is not visible. can't i call the logging module functions from this class?
        print(f'The Value of log is : {log}')
        print(f'dir(log) is : {dir(log)}')
```

Comment: It's not really clear to me what you are trying to do and what goes wrong. Please [edit] your question to provide the full traceback and a [mre] – that means *removing* the parts unnecessary to the question (e.g. the ip handling) and *adding* the parts necessary to run the code.

Comment: If you want to extend logging, you would *inherit* ``CustomLogger`` from ``logging.Logger``: ``class customLogger(logging.Logger):``. However, then it does not make sense to receive a ``logLevel`` (a ``Logger`` only receives a name) , nor to construct a separate ``Logger`` with a ``Handler`` and ``Formatter`` attached – much more than what a ``Logger`` is supposed to do. If you are new to OOP and similar, it might be a good idea to start with a different task: ``logging`` is an ancient module with much borrowed from other language's logging modules, and logging itself is difficult to do well.

Comment: I have edited the post. sorry if I wasn;t clear.

Comment: `custLog` should probably just be a regular function that takes a log level and returns the desired instance of `Logger`; a separate class isn't necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that's your entire class, you can replace it with a single function that takes a log level and returns the instance of `Logger` you want.

```
def make_logger(level):
    logger_name = inspect.stack()[1][3]
    logger = logging.getLogger(logger_name)
    logger.setLevel(level)
    fh = logging.FileHandler("iperf.log", mode='w')
    formatter = fh.setFormatter('%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(name)s : %(message)s')
    fh.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.addHandler(fh)
    return logger
```